# relative sequential compactness in L1 along with convergence in measure implies convergence in L1

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

At the beginning of section 6.2 in "Probability Theory: A comprehensive course" Klenke states: "From the preceding section, we can conclude that convergence in measure plus existence of L1 limit points implies L1-convergence. Hence convergence in measure plus relative sequential compactness in L1 yields convergence in L1. In this section, we study a criterion for relative sequential compactness in L1, the so-called uniform integrability".

I have gone through the preceding sections and I cannot find what Klenke states. What are the theorems or facts that would lead me to Klenke's conclusion?

L1 convergence is defined as $\int |f_n-f|d\mu \xrightarrow{} 0$ as n grows to infinity. Convergence in measure is defined as $\mu(\{d(f_n,f)>\epsilon\}\cap A)\xrightarrow{} 0$ as
$n\xrightarrow{} \infty$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and all $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$

I already know from Athreya about Scheffe's Theorem which requires convergence almost everywhere, convergence in integral and that the limit be integrable, for L1 convergence to result. It seems that Klenke's statement is more general and less restrictive. I suspect that fast convergence in measure may be involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result, as stated, is fasle. Suppose $f_n \to f$ measure but not in $L^{1}$. Then $(f_1,f,f_2,f,f_3,f,\dots)$ is  a counter-example.

What you need is the fact that every subsequence of $(f_n)$ also has limit point in $L^{1}$. Under this assumption here is a proof:

Let $f$ be a limit point of $(f_n)$ in $L^{1}$. There is a subsequence $(f_{m_k})$ of $(f_n)$ converging to $f$ in $L^{1}$, hence also in measure.  Let $f_n \to g$ in measure. Since $(f_{m_k}) \to g$ in measure we conclude that $f=g$ a.e. Thus, $\int |f_{m_k}-g| \to 0$.

This argument can be applied to any subsequence of $(f_n)$ instead of the whole sequence. Conclusion: Every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has  further subsequence converging to $g$ in $L^{1}$. This implies that $\int |f_n-g| \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am a little surprised that there is a simple counterexample to the assertion in the book. Can you point me to a source for the theorem that if every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a further subsequence converging to $g$ in $L^1$ then $f_n$ converges to $g$ in $L^1$?. I know that an analogous result holds for a regular sequence of numbers converging but it does not hold for convergence almost everywhere of sub-subsequence.

Comment: It is true in any metric space. You can  give a proof by contradiction.  Suppose $d(x_n,x)$ does not tend to $0$. Then $d(x_{n_k},x) \geq \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ and some $(n_k)$. Now take a subsequence of $x_{n_k}$ which converges to $x$. Do you see the contradiction now?  @UniformIntegrability

Comment: I think I do. Why does not a similar argument prove the analogous version with almost everywhere convergence?

Comment: @UniformIntegrability Almost everywhere convergence is not given by any metric.

Comment: Thanks again. In your counterexample, you show one sequence that has a convergent subsequence, but I think the statement says that every sequence must have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @UniformIntegrability The statement says 'existence of limit points'. This is vague. I interpret this as saying that the whole sequence has at least one limit point. If every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has  a limit point then the statement in the book is correct , as I have proved. My counter-example is only to pint out this vagueness in the statement.

Comment: I see.  But if it said that every sequence has a limit point, then  the statement is correct?

Comment: @UniformIntegrability Yes, it is correct.

Comment: The term "existence of L1 limit points" is unclear, but the next sentence says "relative sequential compactness in L1," and I am wondering if it implies every sequence in L1 has a convergent subsequence. (I was also confused by Klenke and came across this post).

Comment: In an infinite dimensional normed space there are always bounded  sequences which have no convergent subsequence. @keepfrog

Comment: But I thought the definition of sequential compactness is that every sequence (bounded or not) has a convergent subsequence. "Relative" is when the limit is in the closure of the space according to Klenke. I thought your counterexample can be excluded by assuming relative sequential compactness?